# Send data to Arraylist Android JSOUP

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am downloading data from a website and would like to put it in an ArrayList. I am downloading 2 forms, images and URLS.

```
  ArrayList<String> artistNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> artistImageURLS = new ArrayList<String>();
    int chosen = 0;


    public class nameGetterClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

       Handler handle;
        Document doc;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... strings) {
            try {
                String url = "http://www.billboard.com/charts/artist-100";
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements names = doc.select("div.chart-row__title > h2.chart-row__song");
                for (Element p : names)
                    artistNames.add(p.text());
                  //  Log.i("names,", p.text());
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override  `**<--- ERROR HERE: method does not override superclass**`
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        }
        }
```

I get an error as described in the second last line.

This actually doesnt even add anything to the arraylist, what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... strings) {
            try {
                String url = "http://www.billboard.com/charts/artist-100";
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                Elements names = doc.select("div.chart-row__title > h2.chart-row__song");
                for (Elements p : names)
                    artistNames.add(p.text());
                  //  Log.i("names,", p.text());
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
            }
            return null;
        }
```

please update the line inside the foreach with **Elements** you put Element. If you have still any problem please try to paste the console output which will you got when run in emulator that one makes people understand what the real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with volley library . Its easy and updated 
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

```
ArrayList<String> artistImageURLS = new ArrayList<String>();

String url = "http://my-json-feed";

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

       artistImageURLS.add(response.toString()); 

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

and here the Singleton :

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }
}
```